# I'm using 'Preserve Volume' but my model is still going flat when posed?

Tags: weight-painting, pose-mode

[image]

Did I do something wrong with the model? No matter how I try to weight paint, the leg still flattens. Is my 'Preserve Volume' tick not working?

Comment: Is it a 2D or a 3D mesh? Preserve volume is intended for 3D volumes, and is a little help that cannot be a remedy for bad geometry. If you want counselling on how to improve your deformations I think you should upload your .blend file.

Comment: maybe it's a problem of IK rotation, could you share your file? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: @joshsanfelici Its a 3D model and its a lower poly remake of a character of mine. I can upload the file if you want: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=5710" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/5710/)